# Format column with checkboxes in bootstrap-table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I use [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/), which has [data-formatter](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#column-events-table) feature to format cells. I have a [column with checkboxes](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#checkbox-table) in table. Is there any simple way to format column with checkboxes?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3L7vgcx0/9/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  cellspacing="0" id="mainTable" data-click-to-select="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-pagination="true">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-formatter="starsFormatter"></th>
    <th data-field="name" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
    <th data-field="stargazers_count" data-formatter="starsFormatter" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Stars</th>
    <th data-field="forks_count" data-formatter="forksFormatter" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
    <th data-field="description" data-halign="center" data-align="left" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var data = [{name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"},
           {name: 'ala', stargazers_count: 234, forks_count: 234, description: "asdasdas"}]

$('table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
});

function starsFormatter(row, value, inde) {
    return row + '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i> ';
}

function forksFormatter(value) {
    return '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery"></i> ' + value;
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to format it though? What have you tried?

Comment: @vanburenx with data-formatter attribute and starsFormatter function. Then I tried to format table html structure, but $('table').bootstrapTable rewrite the structure because of data-checkbox attribute.

Comment: I think @vanburenx was asking what sort of formatting you are trying to apply.  Change background color?  Add an icon next to check box?  Add some help text next to the check box?  The answer will depend largely on what sort of formatting you want to do.

Comment: @dmbaughman adding icon next to checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this condition isn't handled in the [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) library.

Issue : calculateObjectValue function is returning expected result but append logic is missed out for both checkbox and radio button (that's why you are not seeing the star icon in checkbox field).

In Code

```
value = calculateObjectValue(column,
                that.header.formatters[j], [value, item, i], value);
```

getting expected value. following code is not appending the value.

```
text = [that.options.cardView ?
                     '<div class="card-view">' : '<td class="bs-checkbox">',
                     '<input' +
                     sprintf(' data-index="%s"', i) +
                     sprintf(' name="%s"', that.options.selectItemName) +
                     sprintf(' type="%s"', type) +
                     sprintf(' value="%s"', item[that.options.idField]) +
                     sprintf(' checked="%s"', value === true ||
                         (value && value.checked) ? 'checked' : undefined) +
                     sprintf(' disabled="%s"', !column.checkboxEnabled ||
                         (value && value.disabled) ? 'disabled' : undefined) +
                     ' />',
                     that.options.cardView ? '</div>' : '</td>'
                 ].join('');
```

so replaced with the below code with a conditional check if the column has formatter then it will append the value.

```
text = [that.options.cardView ?
                        '<div class="card-view">' : '<td class="bs-checkbox">',
                        '<input' +
                        sprintf(' data-index="%s"', i) +
                        sprintf(' name="%s"', that.options.selectItemName) +
                        sprintf(' type="%s"', type) +
                        sprintf(' value="%s"', item[that.options.idField]),
                        column.formatter === undefined ?
                        sprintf(' checked="%s"', value === true ||
                           (value && value.checked) ? 'checked' : undefined) +
                        sprintf(' disabled="%s"', !column.checkboxEnabled ||
                            (value && value.disabled) ? 'disabled' : undefined) +
                        ' />': ' />' + value,
                        that.options.cardView ? '</div>' : '</td>'
                    ].join('');
```

so created [pull-request](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/pull/1391), let see what author says.

Comment: Author accepted the pull-request and merged into the master